# switching bw Javascript and GWT function

Tags: javascript, gwt, static, this, jsni

I am working on a project using GWT and d3. i have used d3 in javascript files. Let me explain a bit more . i have a class name AstForm in GWT. in this class i have a function which  i have called in my javascript file using following code.it  the code works fine for me.

```
public  native void PrepareFunctionsForJS() /*-{
$wnd.ExtractOFFNetWork = this.@org.valcri.asstsrchui.client.AstForm::ExtractOFFNetWork(*);
}-*/;
public  void ExtractOFFNetWork(JsArrayMixed args) 
 {
Window.alert("thisCurrent row and Column is " +
        args.getString(0) + "  " + args.getString(1)+"OffenderNetwork?");
}

void testfunction ()
{
Window.alert("testfunction)
}
```

in java script i have used the following code

```
window.ExtractOFFNetWork(["GWT","JS"]);
```

my code works fine. i can call the ExtractOFFNetWork in javascript file. however the problem is in the ExtractOFFNetWork function when i call testfunction which is also the member function of the ASTFORM class the programe error saying testfunction is not a function. however when i changed testfunction as static than i can access this function within ExtractOFFNetWork. alternatievly i can also use the testfunction inside ExtractOFFNetWork by creating a separate  object of ASTForm as

```
AstForm my =new AstForm();
my.testfunction();
```

however i do not want to use either static or separate ASTform object to access member function of ASTForm. i also used this.testfunction() within ExtractOFFNetWork but it also does not work. i would appreciate if any body can help to solve my problem i have spend full day without any success :)

Answer (score 0):

already tried this when calling your `PrepareFunctionsForJS`(btw by java naming conventions method names start with lowercase letter..)

```
//assuming that you are calling the prepare function from inside the AstForm
public class AstForm() {
   //...
   PrepareFunctionsForJS(this);
}

public  native void PrepareFunctionsForJS(AstForm instance) /*-{
    $wnd.ExtractOFFNetWork = instance.@org.valcri.asstsrchui.client.AstForm::ExtractOFFNetWork(*);
}-*/;
```